# java.io.EOFException being thrown

Tags: java, eofexception

This code is throwing an java.io.EOFException, and I am not sure why this is happening.

```
import java.io.*;

class ReadInts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "intData.dat";

        int sum = 0;

        try {
            DataInputStream instr = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));

            while (true) {
                sum += instr.readInt();
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
                sum += instr.readInt();
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
                sum += instr.readInt();
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
                sum += instr.readInt();

                System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
                instr.close();
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("EOF reached for: " + fileName);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the input file is:

```
0
1
255
-1
```

There is no return character of line feed after -1.

The output I receive is:

```
The sum is: 805974282
The sum is: 1648322068
EOF reaced for: intData.dat
null
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at ReadInts.main(ReadInts.java:18)
```

The output is completely unexpected, and I assume the exception is being thrown because, for whatever reason, the value of sum is great than the maximum value of an int.

I tried changing "int sum = 0" to "long sum = 0" and received the same results.

I commented out the following:

```
        sumOfInts += instr.readInt();
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sumOfInts);
        sumOfInts += instr.readInt();
        // System.out.println("The sum is: " + sumOfInts);
        // sumOfInts += instr.readInt();
        // System.out.println("The sum is: " + sumOfInts);
        // sumOfInts += instr.readInt();
```

After doing this, I received the following exception:

```
The sum is: 805974282
The sum is: 1648322068
Problem reading intData.dat
Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at ReadInts.main(ReadInts.java:14)
```

If it helps, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Thanks for any help.

Tony

Comment: Your reads are in an infinite loop, unless I'm missing something. So you're trying to read after you exhaust the file of lines.  In the example where you commented out code, you try to read after closing the file.

Comment: I guess this may comes from DataInputStream, which may be reading more than you think it does.

Comment: You should close your stream in the `finally` block, under an if stream is null check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that readInt is not reading a string and convert the string to a number; it 
reads four input bytes and returns an int value which it calculates using binary arithmetic.

```
0, \n(13), 1, \n(13) is 1st readInt
2, 5, 5, \n(13) is 2nd readInt
2 is third readInt after which you will get EOF exception
```

One more suggestion would be to close objects like stream in finally block

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String fileName = "C:\\rsc\\intdat.dat";

        int sum = 0;

        DataInputStream instr=null;
        try {
            instr = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));

            while (instr.available()!=0) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(instr.readLine());
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("EOF reached for: " + fileName);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(instr!=null)
            instr.close();
        }

    }
```

PS: InputStream is a binary construct. If you want to read text data use BufferedReader instead

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. The code in the course I am using does not work. I even copied and pasted it to make sure I did not have a typo and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

DataInputStream reads input as bytes in chunk of 4.
So,
0
1
255
-1
0, \n, 1, \n is one readInt
2, 5, 5, \n is other readInt
-1 is third readInt
So, after three readInt, you will get EOF exception as file has been finished.
Also, you should correct out wile loop.